# Can anyone recognize this game?

Tags: steam, pc, mobile

I don't know the name of this game. I saw a replication of it recently in [a video](https://youtu.be/w_8YyMAXexQ?t=571) and remembered that I used to play it as a kid in an old Nokia phone and that I also saw a 3D version of it on Steam some weeks ago.

The goal is to get rid of all enemies by entrapping them in closed shapes, "cutting" them out of the play field.

It looks like this:

[image: Game Image]

The enemies are the smaller dots.

Comment: Reminds me of an old arcade game called Qix. The aim of the game fits with your description

Comment: It's very similar to Qix, but it's not Qix. In Qix, only the player produces a tail, and can enclose territory using the edges of the screen.

Comment: What's the time frame for "old" Nokia phone and "when I was a kid"? If it came preinstalled on a particular model it might be identifiable that way. (Also why is this tagged steam and PC if it's a phone game?)

Comment: Is this actually a picture of the game?

Comment: It's not an image of the game. It's an animation I made that represents it. I tagged it Steam and PC because I also saw one like this on Steam, except it was 3D. The time frame should be 2005-2010, but the Nokia model was akin to the Nokia 3310. One of those with the monochrome green screens. The screen did light up. I could be misremembering the enemies making trails. Can someone write the answer for me to select?

Comment: I'm afraid not.  There's an entire genre of these games, and we require an artifact from the specific game you're wanting to be identified.  It's meant for games you see while watching a movie or TV show, not a game from memory.

Comment: @Frank I don't care about the specific game. I just wanted to know the genre. Which I do, and is why I wanted an answer to select.

Comment: Sorry @Unknow0059, game ID questions are a bit of an endlessly hot-button issue on Arqade. The tag has been hyper-scoped in to be very specific, and unfortunately, a majority of the community has decided that your question doesn't apply to that scope. Sorry.